# How to make jquery validates if the two inputs are the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to do is when a user type an email in the `email` input form it should be the same email in the `reemail` input form. How do i do it in jquery validation?

current output: http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/75/

Comment: This is a poorly written and researched question.  1)  You must show your code in the question itself, not relying on an external link to do it.  2)  Search SO first.  This question has been answered many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `equalTo`

TRY THIS

```
      email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            reemail: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                equalTo: "#email"
            },
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/77/)